# why is last_rx always 0?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I need to get the value of the fields `last_rx` and `trans_start` in a `net_device` struct ... but for some reason `dev->last_rx` is always 0 (`trans_start` has a valid value) ...why is this? Is there another field that gives this value?

here's a snippet

```
struct net_device *dev;
dev = first_net_device(&init_net);

while (dev)
{

        printk(KERN_ALERT "last received time is %li\n", dev->last_rx );
        printk(KERN_ALERT "last transmit time is %li\n", dev->trans_start );
        dev = next_net_device(dev);
}
```

I'm writing a kernel module using linux kernel 2.6.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply added 
`dev->last_rx = jiffies;` 
and it worked! :D

```
struct net_device *dev;
dev = first_net_device(&init_net);

while (dev)
{

        dev->last_rx = jiffies;
        printk(KERN_ALERT "last received time is %li\n", dev->last_rx );
        printk(KERN_ALERT "last transmit time is %li\n", dev->trans_start );
        dev = next_net_device(dev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [these docs](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-17-sect-3), `last_rx` is currently unused, so it's possible that the driver isn't updating that value.

Comment: well is there another way to get that value?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer to your questions is to update the driver.  The driver is responsible for updating the value.  In the for mentioned docs it states the value is unused and it is unused by the kernel, but there are other things that will use it.  If you want to use arp polling with the bonding driver it is required.

From http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-17-sect-3

unsigned long trans_start;

unsigned long last_rx;

Fields that hold a jiffies value. The driver is responsible for updating these values when transmission begins and when a packet is received, respectively. The trans_start value is used by the networking subsystem to detect transmitter lockups. last_rx is currently unused, but the driver should maintain this field anyway to be prepared for future use.

---

see the references to last_rx in the bonding driver here:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt